# python: select a specific section from a very long div class output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am pulling info from a website and the output is very long. how can i select just the key part i am interested in and assign it to a new object

heres the part of the code i am using to pull the info -

```
soup = bs(response.text,"html.parser")
cartl = soup.find("div",{"class":"product-view"})
cart_link = cartl.find_all("form")
```

this is my long output (i shortened it down for the example the full text it pulls is like 100 lines) -

```
<form action="https://www.randomsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL25pa2UtYWlyLWpvcmRhbi0xMy1yZXRyby1iZy1oaXN0b3J5LW9mLWZsaWdodC13aGl0ZS1tZXRhbGljLXNpbHZlci11bml2ZXJzaXR5LXJlZC00MTQ1NzQtMTAzP19fX1NJRD1V/product/92797/form_key/NBlK6IE3LYdwf0Vh/" id="product_addtocart_form" method="post">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="NBlK6IE3LYdwf0Vh"/>
<div class="no-display">
<input name="product" type="hidden" value="92797"/>
<input id="related-products-field" name="related_product" type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
```

i want to take  this a add this to a new object- `https://www.randomsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL25pa2UtYWlyLWpvcmRhbi0xMy1yZXRyby1iZy1oaXN0b3J5LW9mLWZsaWdodC13aGl0ZS1tZXRhbGljLXNpbHZlci11bml2ZXJzaXR5LXJlZC00MTQ1NzQtMTAzP19fX1NJRD1V/product/92797/form_key/NBlK6IE3LYdwf0Vh/`

this is the new updated code via the answer below thanks for that-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.session()
endpoint = "https://randomsite.com/"
response = session.get(endpoint)

soup0 = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

div = soup0.find("div",{"class":"product-view"})
html = div.find("form")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
form = soup.find('form', { 'id': 'product_addtocart_form' })
action = form['action']
print(action)
```

this is the new error i am getting any idea on where I'm going wrong -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 191, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BeautifulSoup `find` method to get a reference to the `<form>` tag (optionally filtering on a particular `id` in case there are multiple forms on the page).  Then, treat the form object like a dictionary to pull the `action` attribute.

### Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<form action="https://www.randomsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL25pa2UtYWlyLWpvcmRhbi0xMy1yZXRyby1iZy1oaXN0b3J5LW9mLWZsaWdodC13aGl0ZS1tZXRhbGljLXNpbHZlci11bml2ZXJzaXR5LXJlZC00MTQ1NzQtMTAzP19fX1NJRD1V/product/92797/form_key/NBlK6IE3LYdwf0Vh/" id="product_addtocart_form" method="post">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="NBlK6IE3LYdwf0Vh"/>
<div class="no-display">
<input name="product" type="hidden" value="92797"/>
<input id="related-products-field" name="related_product" type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
form = soup.find('form', { 'id': 'product_addtocart_form' })
action = form['action']
print action
```

### Output

```
https://www.randomsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL25pa2UtYWlyLWpvcmRhbi0xMy1yZXRyby1iZy1oaXN0b3J5LW9mLWZsaWdodC13aGl0ZS1tZXRhbGljLXNpbHZlci11bml2ZXJzaXR5LXJlZC00MTQ1NzQtMTAzP19fX1NJRD1V/product/92797/form_key/NBlK6IE3LYdwf0Vh/
```